# PrimeVue menu component - Uncaught TypeError: this.$refs.menu.toggle is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primevue

I have the following template for showing PrimeVue menu.

```
<template>
   <div>
      <i class="pi pi-ellipsis-v" @click="onActionClick"></i>
      <Menu :model="items" :popup="true" ref="menu" />
   </div>
</template>

data() {
    return {
        items: [
            { label: 'New', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus' },
            { label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash' }
        ]
    }
},
methods: {
    onActionClick(event) {
        this.$refs.menu.toggle(event);
    }
}
```

Now when I click, I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.$refs.menu.toggle is not a function
```

how can I fix this ?

Comment: Is there a `toggle` function in the `Menu` component? (Can we see the `Menu` component?)

Comment: Yes. It has. https://primevue.org/menu/#api.menu.methods

Comment: It should work. See this example- https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2FApp.vue

Comment: This link is not working

Comment: See this, try in codesandbox- https://primevue.org/menu/#popup

Comment: I have added `this.$refs.menu[0].toggle(event)` and it is working fine now.